# How can I solve this error: [eslint] Error while loading rule 'vuetify/no-legacy-grid' when try upgrade vuetify 2.6.13

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, eslint

Trying upgrade vuetify 1.5 to 2.6.13, and the after "npm run serve" i got this error in the terminal:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                          13:22:08

[eslint] Error while loading rule 'vuetify/no-legacy-grid': context.parserServices.defineTemplateBodyVisitor is not a function
Occurred while linting C:\Users\...\src\main.js

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
ERROR in [eslint] Error while loading rule 'vuetify/no-legacy-grid': context.parserServices.defineTemplateBodyVisitor is not a function
Occurred while linting C:\Users\...\src\main.js

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

i upgrade some dependencies for this subject and i have these versions:

> "vue": "^2.7.14",
> "vuetify": "^2.6.13",
> "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
> "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
> "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
> "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
> "eslint": "^8.31.0",
> "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.8.0",
> "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^1.1.0",
> "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.5.8",

I tried the /* eslint-disable */ and did not work

in my .eslintrc.js have the rule like this:

> "rules": {
> "vuetify/no-legacy-grid": "error",}

Comment: Is it possible that you're using the old `v-flex`? In general: such errors are not to be suppressed, they point out that there's something you need to fix (or in your case, migrate) and you should do that. What's the point in updating the dependency to the new version but not your own code?

Comment: Thnxs for your comment @Fred, i already changed `v-flex` for `v-col` also v-layout for v-row, but still have the error. I hoped the eslint plugin resolve it, or more instructions about  what else to change, i am not expert, i have not enough migrating experience

Comment: There is an upgrade guide that explains how to upgrade from Vuetify 1.5.x to 2.0.x: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/ That should help you. Be aware that you're migrating to 2.x while 3.x was just released. It is officially still in beta but only because the docs are not completely migrated yet. The features are stable. I recommend skipping 2.x and migrating to 3.x right away unless you need the components that are still missing in Vuetify 3!